# How to choose a valid case execution?

Tags: go

I use `https://github.com/google/goexpect` as my shell interaction, PPPoE dialing program, My operating system CentOS7, my dialing program rp-pppoe, For the first time, such as 1.
How do I write goexpect interactions when I dial?

I know where the problem is and I don't know how to solve it. When I create a dial with concurrency, the logic of the first interaction is different from that of the subsequent one. For example, the content of the second article is different from the content of the first article, and it adds a new question: `(default ppp0) or enter 'n' if you Want to create a new one:` , I saw that `goexpect` has an operation of `ExpectSwitchCase`, but I don't quite understand how to solve my problem with it. How to match one of the interaction logics and ignore other conditions.

1. The first time the interaction is performed

```sh
Welcome to the PPPoE client setup.  First, I will run some checks on
your system to make sure the PPPoE client is installed properly...


LOGIN NAME

Enter your Login Name (default root): USER
```

2. When I execute the second interaction, How to use `google/goexpect` to match one in multiple conditions, and continue to perform the next step

```
Welcome to the PPPoE client setup.  First, I will run some checks on
your system to make sure the PPPoE client is installed properly...

The following DSL config was found on your system:

  Device:      Name:
  ppp0         DSLppp0

Please enter the device if you want to configure the present DSL config
(default ppp0) or enter 'n' if you want to create a new one:n
LOGIN NAME

Enter your Login Name: USER
```

3. My code, But it can't work properly

```
package shell

import (
    "fmt"
    expect "github.com/google/goexpect"
    "github.com/google/goterm/term"
    "regexp"
    "time"
)


func R(user, password, dev string) error {
    fmt.Println(term.Bluef("Telnet spawner example"))

    to := 3 * time.Second
    exec, _, err := expect.Spawn("/usr/sbin/pppoe-setup", to)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer exec.Close()

    r, rs, _, err := exec.ExpectSwitchCase([]expect.Caser{
        &expect.Case{R: regexp.MustCompile(`Enter your Login Name \(default root\):`), S: user + "\n", T: expect.Next(), Rt: 0},
        &expect.Case{R: regexp.MustCompile(`or enter 'n' if you want to create a new one:`), S: "n\n"},
    }, to)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("r:rs:", r, rs)
    ur, urs, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Enter your Login Name`), to)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("ur:urs:", ur, urs)


    if err := exec.Send(user + "\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here03:", err.Error())
        return err
    }

    dr, drs, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`\(default eth0\):`), to)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here04:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(dr, drs)

    if err := exec.Send(dev + "\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here05:", err.Error())

        return err
    }

    er, ers, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Enter the demand value \(default no\):`), to)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here06:", err.Error())

        return err
    }

    fmt.Println(er, ers)

    if err := exec.Send("\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here06x:", err.Error())

        return err
    }
    if _, _, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Enter the DNS information here:`), to); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here06x:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    if err := exec.Send("\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here07:", err.Error())

        return err
    }
    if _, _, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Please enter your Password:`), to); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here08:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    if err := exec.Send(password + "\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("sendhere08:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    if _, _, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Please re-enter your Password:`), to); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here0801:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    if err := exec.Send(password + "\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("sendhere0801:", err.Error())
        return err
    }

    if _, _, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`normal user to start or stop DSL connection \(default yes\):`), to); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here09:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    if err := exec.Send("yes\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here10:", err.Error())
        return err
    }

    if _, _, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Choose a type of firewall \(0-2\):`), to); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here11:", err.Error())

        return err
    }
    if err := exec.Send("0\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here12:", err.Error())

        return err
    }

    if _, _, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Please enter no or yes \(default no\):`), to); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here13:", err.Error())

        return err
    }
    if err := exec.Send("yes\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here14:", err.Error())

        return err
    }

    fr, frs, err := exec.Expect(regexp.MustCompile(`Accept these settings and adjust configuration files \(y/n\)?`), to);
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here15:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(fr,frs)

    if err := exec.Send("y\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here16:", err.Error())

        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

4. This is the main file @Josh Chappelle

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seraphico/ppps/pkg/shell"
)

func main() {
    err := shell.R("test01", "test01", "br3")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on what exactly doesn't work properly? What happens when you run the code? I don't see a main function so is this only part of the code?

Comment: "But it can't work properly", what do you expect to happen and what is happening instead? Are you getting any errors, if so please add it to your question.

Comment: @JoshChappelle E.g

The logic of the first interaction

1. Please enter and exit the username:

2. Please enter the password.

3. login

Second interaction logic:

1. Please enter your first name.

2. Please enter your username

3. Please enter the password.

4. login

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I can fix it.

```
ro, _, _, err := exec.ExpectSwitchCase([]expect.Caser{
    &expect.Case{R: regexp.MustCompile("if you want to create a new one:"), S: "n\n", T: expect.Next(), Rt: 1},
    &expect.Case{R: regexp.MustCompile(`Enter your Login Name:`), S: user + "\n", Rt: 0},
    &expect.Case{R: regexp.MustCompile(`Enter your Login Name \(default root\):`), S: user + "\n", Rt: 0},
    }, to)
if err != nil {
        return err
}
```

if `if you want to create a new one:`If the matching is unsuccessful, the join t status is next and set Rt 1.